# Как вывести преобразованную строку из Json?

Tags: json, php

Здравствуйте! Не могу вывести преобразованную строку из Json:

```
$str_data = file_get_contents("yql.json");
$data = json_decode($str_data,true);
foreach($data as $k){
echo $k;
}
    {"results":
    {"quote":
        [
        {"Symbol":"TIBX",
            "Date":"2013-12-31",
            "Open":"22.70",
            "High":"22.86",
            "Low":"22.46",
            "Close":"22.48",
            "Volume":"1727900",
            "Adj_Close":"22.48"
        },
        {"Symbol":"TIBX",
            "Date":"2013-12-30",
            "Open":"22.48",
            "High":"22.76",
            "Low":"22.32",
            "Close":"22.67",
            "Volume":"1743300",
            "Adj_Close":"22.67"
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

Вывести без `print_r($k);`, а через `echo`. Формат вывода:

```
2013-12-31 22.70 22.86 22.46 22.48 1727900 22.48
2013-12-30 22.48 22.76 22.32 22.67 1743300 22.67
```

Comment: @Dmitriy8787, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: @Dmitriy8787, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach($data as $k){
    echo $k['results']['quote'][0]['Symbol'];
}
```

Мое решение подстройте под свой формат вывода.

Более подробно можете [тут схожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758954/get-data-from-json-file-with-php) и [тут справку](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) почитать о работе с JSON в PHP.